# go : How function with different return type than declaration is working fine in golang

Tags: go

I'm new to golang programming and I'm learning about interfaces in go.

When googled I stumbled upon this [blog](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/07/interface-semantics.html) in ardan labs. The below snippet is found in the *listing 5*. The complete code is on go playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Hk7FuovsTH)

```
type errorString struct {
    s string
}

func New(text string) error {
    return errorString{text}
}
```

In the New method, return statement is returning a struct of type `errorString` but the function declaration says the type should be `error`. The above code doesn't throw any error. It compiles and works fine.

When I changed the method as below still it works fine.

```
func New(text string) errorString {
    return errorString{text}
}
```

How does this incompatible types work in go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `error` type is an interface type.Here is the interface's declaration:

```
type error interface {
    Error() string
}
```

`errorString` is a implementation of error interface.
That's why it works for `errorString` type.

You can find more details about interface [here](https://medium.com/rungo/interfaces-in-go-ab1601159b3a)